# How to escape special characters in SPARQL Prefixed Names?

Tags: python, escaping, character, sparql, dbpedia

I'm making requests to DBPedia using SPARQL and Python.

Sadly, I'm always getting an error when I send requests with special characters (like parenthesis).

I tried to escape it with backslashes (as in code below) but it's not working.

I read that I could specify the entire URI but it doesn't work either (but I might have not done it the right way).

Does anybody have another option or could provide an example of how I can write my request with the entire URI, considering the request I already have?

```
query = """
    PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
    SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o WHERE {
       {
           ?s ?p ?o
           FILTER (?s=:Grimaldi_\(crater\))

       }
    }
    """
```

Here is the error I get:

> `QueryBadFormed: QueryBadFormed: a bad request has been sent to the endpoint, probably the sparql query is bad formed.`
>
> `Response:`
>   `b"Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 0: Bad character '\\' (0x5c) in SPARQL expression at '\\'\n\nSPARQL query:\n\n#output-format:application/sparql-results+json\n\n    PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>\nSELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o WHERE {\n       {\n       ?s ?p ?o\n       FILTER (?s=:Grimaldi_\\(crater\\))\n\n       }\n}\n"`

Comment: I think there's an extra `)` at the end of the query

Comment: No actually it's just because this query is a part of some code that I didn't post here... I just forgot to remove the ```)``` in the post. But thanks for noticing, I edited it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [full URI definitely works](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++%7B%0D%0A+++++++%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo%0D%0A+++++++FILTER+%28+%3Fs+%3D+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FGrimaldi_%28crater%29%3E+%29%0D%0A+++%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+), as --

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o WHERE {
   {
       ?s ?p ?o
       FILTER ( ?s = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Grimaldi_(crater)> )
   }
}
```

<strike>There is an open bug in Virtuoso v7's handling of Prefixed Names with backslash escaping (such as your `:Grimaldi_\(crater\)`  with `PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>`, or the more common `dbr:Grimaldi_\(crater\)` with `PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>`).  Please add your voice to [the github issue](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/318), to help raise its priority.</strike>

The backslash-escaping in prefixed names now works as it should in Virtuoso 7 (07.20.3230, as of [commit 5f68a2e2f2, 2019-04-01](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/commit/6f46c8b944dec7cef9b28ff152f5853fa77f627f)), which backs the DBpedia instance.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly with this solution. My synthax was wrong when trying with the full URI.
Will definitely leave a comment on GitHub about the backslash!

Comment: So... any ETA on .3230 release?

Comment: @Amadan - Assuming you're using Open Source Edition (a/k/a VOS), you can build `07.20.3230` from the `develop/7` branch. If you need it to be in `stable/7`, please add your voice to [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/318).

Comment: Yeah, I’m not confident I can build from source, the system is pretty locked down, full of old versions, and I had compilation problems before with other software, so I was relying on VOS binaries. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Which characters need to be escaped in full URI syntax? I assume it is `<`, `>`, `\\`?

Comment: @phil294 — I don't know that I understand your question, which should probably *be* a question (not a comment on an answer). ["Full URI syntax [of SPARQL]"](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) uses standard HTTP/S URIs, as defined in [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), with each URI wrapped in angle-brackets (i.e., `<` and `>`), and which uses ["percent encoding" a/k/a/ "URL encoding"](http://dbpedia.org/page/Percent-encoding) for reserved characters.

Answer (score 1):

We have fixed this issue (which was specific to the 7.x rather than the more recent 8.x release) and applied it to the Virtuoso instances behind the DBpedia-Snapshot and DBpedia-Live instances.

**Query:**

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o WHERE {
       {
           ?s ?p ?o
           FILTER (?s=:Grimaldi_\(crater\))

       }
    }
```

**Live DBpedia-Snapshot SPARQL Query Definition:** [Link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fs%3D%3AGrimaldi_%5C%28crater%5C%29%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000)

**Live DBpedia-Live SPARQL Query Definition:** [Link](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fs%3D%3AGrimaldi_%5C%28crater%5C%29%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000)

Another example based on a comma (`,`) in the url. Note the original query has been changed to add the backslash (`\`) in order for it to work.

**Query:**

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX grs: <http://www.georss.org/georss/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT ?label ?country ?isPartOf ?_type ?capital ?lcity ?geopoint
WHERE {
        { dbr:Eraring\,_New_South_Wales rdfs:label ?label  .  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), "en"))}
          UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring\,_New_South_Wales dbo:country ?country} }
          UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring\,_New_South_Wales dbo:isPartOf ?isPartOf}}
          UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring\,_New_South_Wales <http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/hypernym> ?_type}}
          UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring\,_New_South_Wales dbo:capital ?capital}}
          UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring\,_New_South_Wales dbo:largestCity ?lcity}}
          UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring\,_New_South_Wales grs:point ?geopoint}}
  }
```

**Live SPARQL Query Definition:** [Link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20grs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.georss.org%2Fgeorss%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20geo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Flabel%20%3Fcountry%20%3FisPartOf%20%3F_type%20%3Fcapital%20%3Flcity%20%3Fgeopoint%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20dbr%3AEraring%5C%2C_New_South_Wales%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%20.%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%2C%20%22en%22%29%29%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%7BOPTIONAL%7Bdbr%3AEraring%5C%2C_New_South_Wales%20dbo%3Acountry%20%3Fcountry%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%7BOPTIONAL%7Bdbr%3AEraring%5C%2C_New_South_Wales%20dbo%3AisPartOf%20%3FisPartOf%7D%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%7BOPTIONAL%7Bdbr%3AEraring%5C%2C_New_South_Wales%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Flinguistics%2Fgold%2Fhypernym%3E%20%3F_type%7D%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%7BOPTIONAL%7Bdbr%3AEraring%5C%2C_New_South_Wales%20dbo%3Acapital%20%3Fcapital%7D%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%7BOPTIONAL%7Bdbr%3AEraring%5C%2C_New_South_Wales%20dbo%3AlargestCity%20%3Flcity%7D%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%7BOPTIONAL%7Bdbr%3AEraring%5C%2C_New_South_Wales%20grs%3Apoint%20%3Fgeopoint%7D%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000)